# Headless Wordpress with user authentication

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, authentication, headless

I've set up af headless WP with a ReactJS frontend. My idea is to use the WP backend to store and manage content that users create. I want people to be able to sign up and login to my site, and create their own content. But my problem is, that I need a guide/tutorial how to do is. Should I use the JWT authentication plugin and how do I create users (does not have to be WP users)?

Any ideas?

Thanks Kasper

Answer (score 1):

First you must create WordPress users as the WordPress code checks the capabilities of the current user to allow write access to its data. WordPress supports a [REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/) that allows front end JavaScript to access its data. It by default uses [cookie authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) to control access. However, there are actions/filters so you can implement your own authentication. If you use the default cookie authentication then you can use the WordPress login facilities to handle authentication. The supported JavaScript client is a [Backbone client](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/). I don't know if that will work well with ReactJS (I don't know ReactJS) so you may need to some work with the front-end client side.

Incidentally, the WordPress Calypso project uses a ReactJS frontend to access the WordPress backend. I don't know this project so I don't have an opinion. My feeling is that WordPress decided on Backbone before ReactJS became well known but ReactJS is actually much better so they have the Calypso project. You can read that code to get ideas.

Comment: Hi Magenta, thanks for your input. I dont want to create users in the WP admin for them to login. The users should be able to create a profile for them self and then start creating content.

Comment: If you use the WordPress code to manage the content you will need WordPress users as the WordPress code checks if the current user has write access to the content. You can of course write your own code to manage the content but then you will be redoing much of WordPress. A WordPress user can be specifically tailored to have only certain capabilities so you can created users with very restricted capabilities.

Comment: Further, WordPress can be setup so a first time user can create his own login, i.e. you don't need an admin to manually create a user.

Comment: No you are right, I dont want to redo the entire WP code So can I create a new wordpress user with the WP API? Because then my problem would be solved, I guess?

Comment: The WP REST API cannot be used to create a new wordpress user as it requires authentication before it allows you to create anything. You can display a form to the user to enter a username, password and an email address and then you will need to write code to handle this form submission and create the user using wp_insert_user().